# Gstreamer OpenCV delay in receiving frames

Tags: python, opencv, udp, gstreamer

I am trying read a gstreamer pipline using OpenCV in real time. There is a delay of about 0.8-1 seconds which is around 40 frames in my case.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5200 ! application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000 , encoding-name=(string)H264 , payload=(int)96  ! queue ! rtph264depay ! queue ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

This is a real time application and OpenCV needs to process the latest data coming from the G streamer pipeline and execute some commands.

As far as I have checked OpenCV has the issue of delay due to inability to set buffersize(only supported on DS 1394 v2.x video backend) to 1. If thats the case is there any alternative to reading gstreamer pipeline in real time other than OpenCV?

Any ideas on fixing this lag?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce the rtp jitter buffer latency in the gstreamer pipeline.

`! rtpjitterbuffer latency=200 !`